# Oracle | Update huge table after comparing values with other table

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update

I have two huge tables. Let's call them as `ITEM` table (1807236 records) and `ITEM_PROD_DUMP` table (796369 records).
I need to update two columns (`total_volume_amount, total_volume_uom`) from `ITEM` table with the values of second table `ITEM_PROD_DUMP` where their primary key (`SYS_ITEM_ID`) matches.

I have written a query to do so, it works but only for handful records. For these huge number of records, it just keeps on running.

Can anyone please help me to write a correct and optimal query.

**Query I have written:**

```
update item i set i.total_volume_amount = (select ipd.total_volume_amount
                                            from item_prod_dump ipd
                                            where i.sys_item_id = ipd.sys_item_id),
i.total_volume_uom = (select ipd.total_volume_uom
                    from item_prod_dump ipd
                    where i.sys_item_id = ipd.sys_item_id)
where exists (select ipd.total_volume_amount
            from item_prod_dump ipd
            where i.sys_item_id = ipd.sys_item_id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `MERGE` statement.  Pure and simple.  1.8 million records is not a "huge" number of records.

```
merge into item t
using ( SELECT  *
        FROM    item_prod_dump ipd ) u
on ( t.sys_item_id = u.sys_item_id )
when matched then update set t.total_volume_amount = u.total_volume_amount,
                             t.total_volume_uom = u.total_volume_uom;
```

Comment: Thank you Matthew! Let me try this.